# Core Data In Fetch request again insert duplicate value

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am learning core data so while doing one example on core data I have stuck up in the bellow question :

Whenever I call Fetch request one New data has been inserted. Could someone help me in this ?

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{

    NSString *svd = self.text1.text;
    AppDelegate * appdel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];


        NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Students" inManagedObjectContext: appdel.managedObjectContext];



    [entity setValue:svd forKey:@"name"];
    NSError *error;
   BOOL isSaved= [appdel.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    NSLog(@"Sucessfully Saved %d",isSaved);

}

- (IBAction)fetch:(id)sender
{

    AppDelegate * appdel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Students" inManagedObjectContext:appdel.managedObjectContext];


    //Create a Fetch Request.
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetch setEntity:entity];

    //Save all fetched rows in mutable array.

    arr =[[appdel.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil]mutableCopy];

    //coredata returns each row as managed object so we save that in array
    for (NSManagedObject *obj in arr )
    {
//        NSString *ans = [obj valueForKey:@"name"];
//  
//        [savedata addObject:ans];

        NSLog(@"Names : %@",[obj valueForKey:@"name"]);


    }

//     [tableview reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Your code works fine but need some 'refactoring' for clarity and has one non-critical 'typo' :-) What do you expect from it? Maybe you have wrong project settings or wrong  core data stack setup?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Please specify what you expect to happen, and what is happening, then ask a clear question.

Comment: Your `save:` method creates a new instance every time you call it, but your code doesn't show that you are ever calling it. Your question is unclear, it's impossible to tell what's wrong with the information you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for your Response, I have done a mistake in connection, In delete button I have connected save method as well as fetch method so whenever I click fetch button one duplicate has been saved.